# How can I put my form multiple places in my post?

Tags: cognito-forms

I put Cognito forms in multiple places in my post but they end up sticking together and don't appear where I want them to be.

Can you please tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We do not currently support the ability to have more then one Cognito Form on a page or in a post, unless you place the second and third forms into iframes. The ability to add more then one form to a page is something that we are looking into and working on for future releases.